# Select2 offset when you scroll down

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I'm using the AngularJS module from Angular-UI.  When I scroll up a bit and the dropdown area disappears while I'm scrolling.  I use box-sizing on our site and bootstrap2.

Is there a common solution for this?

```
<select ng-model='newConversation.user_ids' multiple class='span12' placeholder="Add people..." ui-select2>
    <option value='{{ user.id }}' ng-repeat='user in serieUsers | filter:isCurrentUser'>
        {{ user.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

[image: select2 issue]

Comment: Select2 has on scroll events to determine whether the dropdown panel falls out of the page. When this happens it often flips the dropdown panel upwards. This can be noticed on the [Select2 demo page](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

I'm wondering whether you have an overflow:hidden on the container or z-index of the elements above cover the panel. Check out the panel in the inspector when it "disappears" and it will generally outline or show where the panel is on DOM element hover.

Comment: @ArtofThem it happens when a class called `select2-drop-above` is toggled on.